# Callback - error after 2nd callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, asynccallback

I'm learning about callbacks and I wrote this code:

```
var http = require('http');
var str = "";
var count = 2;
function jugglingAsync(callback){
    http.get(process.argv[count], function(response){
        response.on("data", function(data){
            str+=data.toString();
        })
        response.on("end", function(){
            console.log(str);
            str = "";
            count++;
            if(count<5) callback();
        })
    })
}
jugglingAsync(jugglingAsync);
```

It should collect 3 URL adresses given as command-line arguments. Problem is - when first callback works fine and print good result, the second gives me an error:

```
            if(count<5) callback();
                        ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/dzikichrzan/Gdrive/Programowanie/JavaScript/learnyounode/jugglingAsync.js:13:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:73:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:167:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:906:12)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:455:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:17)
```

Why this function works fine only one time?

Comment: If it says `callback` is not a function, what does it say that it **is**? `console.log` it.

Comment: looks like you would need to write `if (count<5) callback(callback);`

Comment: At first time is shows 'callback' as 'undefined' and it crashes at second 'console.log'.

Comment: @jcarpenter That worked! Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

You are calling jugglingAsync in

if(count<5) callback();

With no parameters, which is expecting a parameter as a callback function

Comment: Right. So the first time through is no problem, but the second time has `callback` undefined.